# Why is timezone converted when putting date-time into vector in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Why is the timezone changed when putting a datetime value into a vector in R? (Using the `lubridate` package to create the datetime value)

```
lubridate::now(tz = "UTC")
#> "2018-05-25 20:11:16 UTC"

c(lubridate::now(tz = "UTC"))
#> "2018-05-25 16:11:16 EDT"
```

(I'm in the Eastern timezone)

Comment: See also `?c.POSIXct` and [c(a, b) for POSIXct objects with tzone attributes?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2012-July/317759.html)